# How do I know the has of commits after a PR is merged?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to implement some code that:

1. Inspects a bunch of merged pull requests from `upstream/main`
2. In certain conditions, cherry-pick the commits from the PR to a local branch.

One thing I noticed from github is, the commit hash in the pull request sometimes gets changed when it is merged into the `main` branch. I am wondering

1. Why it happens?
2. How do I track the commit SHA in this case?

@schwern -- The output of `git log --decorate --graph --oneline upstream/main` looks like:

```
* 862c7e2ee
* 2e33b0547
* 7bec340d9
* 951748c89
* 7076c050d
*   a31f0e164 
|\
| * 29161b2fd 
* | 5a80cb389 
* | a7217055c 
* | 568518b6a 
* | 7e4d4d652
* | 4be3c3e7f
* | f5c92ca2d 
* | 0f0eb7c2b 
|/
*   f93a4c877 
|\
| * 36415a25f 
| * 15d59cbf2
* | 98c982d91
* |   bcc89944f
|\ \
| * | ec83f920d
* | |   19cc2e4d4
|\ \ \
| * | | 0cb401a8c
* | | |   6fc65bbe4
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
```

Comment: A pull request does not have a commit hash. The individual commits do. 1) Are you referring to the last commit in a PR? 2) How are you merging PRs? [(Squash, Rebase, Merge)](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github) 3) What is the purpose of the cherry-picking? There might be a better way.

Comment: @Schwern 1) Here I mean *all* the commits in the pull request. 2) We are merging the PRs 3) The reason for cherry-picking is that when we release a new version of our product, we cut at a given `main` hash (stop introducing new features), but we still want to cherry-pick the bugfixes. Not sure if there is a better choice, but it seems this is what we are currently doing right now.

Comment: If you "are merging the PRs" the commit IDs should not change. If you are using "squash" or "rebase merge" the commit IDs will always change. If the commit IDs change "sometimes", then I think that means "sometimes" someone is using something other than merge. (And strangely, I don't think GitHub shows you which strategy was used after completing a PR.)

Comment: If you're truly merging the PRs, the commit hashes should not change; it should only create a merge commit. You're probably rebasing somewhere. Can we see `git log --decorate --graph --oneline upstream/main`? Just enough to see the commits for a few PRs.

Comment: @TTT It’s unfortunate that Git terminology for “merge” also encompasses a so-called fast-forward, so we always have to give these caveats when talking about “merges”. (I also have issues with the “squash merge” terminology—which is more like a specific kind of _rebase_, IMO.)

Comment: @Schwern -- I suppose we sometimes do fast-forward. I am pasting the output of the command you mentioned.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do a regular fast-forward merge using the GitHub web UI. (Though I believe you can do it in a git client and push it out, which could auto-complete the PR if conditions are satisfied.) Also, a fast-forward "merge", like a regular merge with a merge commit, doesn't change any commit IDs. But if you use "rebase merge" the rebase portion rewrites the commit IDs, and then it performs a fast-forward merge of those new commit IDs. I'm guessing commit `a31f0e164` is from a PR with a regular merge, and commits `7076c050d..862c7e2ee` are IDs that changed from a PR with rebase merge?

Comment: @TTT I suppose so. It seems we do all kinds of merge.

Comment: That 7076c050d..862c7e2ee contain no merges is suspicious. Either you're allowing direct pushes to main, or each commit is a squash merge, or both. Similarly 29161b2fd, what is that commit? A squash or a direct push to main?

Comment: @Schwern They look like direct push; they are simple commits, not merge commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the commit hashes are changing, you're not doing simple PR merges. And your `git log` suggests there's other non-PR things happening to your main branch.

---

There are [three types of PR merges on Github](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/about-merge-methods-on-github).

## "Merge pull request"

This is the equivalent of `git merge --no-ff`. It's a normal merge. A merge commit is created. All commit IDs remain the same.

```
# Before PR merge
A - B - C [main]
     \
      1 - 2- 3 [feature]

# After "merge pull request"
A - B - C ---- M [main]
    \         /
     1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

`--no-ff` prevents "fast-forwards"; it will always create a merge commit even if one is not necessary.

```
A - B [main]
     \
      1 - 2- 3 [feature]

# After `git merge feature`
A - B - 1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
                  [main]

# After `git merge --no-ff feature` (equivalent to "merge pull request")
A - B --------- M [main]
     \        /
      1 - 2- 3 [feature]
```

## "Squash and merge"

This isn't really a merge. It takes the changes in the PR and squashes them into a single new commit. You can do this on the command line with `--squash`.

```
# Before PR merge
A - B - C [main]
     \
      1 - 2- 3 [feature]

# After "squash and merge"
A - B - C - 123 [main]
    \
     1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

## "Rebase and merge"

This also isn't really a merge. It rewrites each commit in the PR as if they were committed directly to main. There is no merge commit. It is similar to `git rebase main`.

This will result in new commit IDs.

```
# Before PR merge
A - B - C [main]
     \
      1 - 2- 3 [feature]

# After "rebase and merge"
# Z1 is commit 1 rewritten on top of C.
# Z2 is commit 2 rewritten on top of Z1.
# Z3 is commit 3 rewritten on top of Z2.
A - B - C - Z1 - Z2 - Z3 [main]
    \
     1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

---

## Main branch protection?

There's another thing to consider... if your main branch is not protected, people can be making changes to main directly. This can include pushing commits directly to main, and doing rebases and amends to main commits. Rebases and amends will cause commits to have new IDs.

You can [protect your main branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches) which will disallow forced pushes. You can go further and lock the main branch; nothing can be pushed to the branch, the only way to modify main is via a PR. This is very good practice in a collaborative environment where unreviewed changes to main can affect many people's work.

---

## What's going on?

Looking at your history, a lot. It's impossible to tell exactly, but we can make some educated guesses.

```
 * 862c7e2ee
 * 2e33b0547
 * 7bec340d9
 * 951748c89
 * 7076c050d
```

Since the above history is linear, it is not a normal PR merge. They could be commits pushed directly to main, or a PR which has been "rebased and merged", or a series of "squash and merge", or any combination.

```
*   a31f0e164 
|\
| * 29161b2fd 
* | 5a80cb389 
* | a7217055c 
* | 568518b6a 
* | 7e4d4d652
* | 4be3c3e7f
* | f5c92ca2d 
* | 0f0eb7c2b 
|/
```

a31f0e164 is a merge commit. The first parent of a merge commit is the branch you merged into (main), so 5a80cb389, a7217055c, etc... were all added to main after the branch was made. They are, again, linear which suggests a direct push to main, "rebase and merge", or a series of "squash and merge", or any combination.

The merged branch had just one commit: 29161b2fd.

```
*   f93a4c877 
|\
| * 36415a25f 
| * 15d59cbf2
* | 98c982d91
* |   bcc89944f
|\ \
| * | ec83f920d
* | |   19cc2e4d4
|\ \ \
| * | | 0cb401a8c
* | | |   6fc65bbe4
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
```

f93a4c877 is a merge commit. Its branch began before all the other commits. That branch contained 36415a25f and 15d59cbf2.

Between that branch being created and merged, three other branches were merged (merge commits 6fc65bbe4, 19cc2e4d4, and bcc89944f. All these branches were made even earlier.

98c982d91 was either a direct push to main, rebase & merge, or squash merge.

---

## Recommendations

### Do not rely on commit IDs.

Commit IDs are central to how Git works. Your commit history is not written in stone. There's many legitimate reasons to need change history and thus to change commit IDs. Embrace that.

If you need to identify a particular location in history, use tags, or a marker in the merge commit message.

### Protect your main branch.

To directly address your "commit IDs are changing" issue...

- Protect your main branch to disallow force pushes.
- Lock your main branch to disallow pushes.
- Disallow "rebase and merge" and "squash merge".

  - Or embrace them and accept that commit IDs are volatile.

Other good ideas...

- Require reviews and checks for PR merges.
- Auto-delete branches after merging.
- Require branches to be up to date before merging.

That last one ensures the code you test in the branch is the same as the code being merged.